# Why cant I get the divs to change onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm tryin to make a very simple website and I just want the two divs to change as I click on the corresponding list button on top.But the second div never shows up when I click on the second list button. Can't figure out why for hours now, all steps in the code seem logical. I want to do this without Jquery or anything else.

```js
window.onload = function() {
d1 = document.getElementById('myDiv1');
d2 = document.getElementById('myDiv2');
function showDiv1() {
  if( d2.style.display == "block" )
  {
    d2.style.display = "none";
    d1.style.display = "block";
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

function showDiv2() {
  if( d1.style.display == "block" )
  {
    d1.style.display = "none";
    d2.style.display = "block";
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.myDiv1, .myDiv2 {
  background-image: url("paper.jpg");
  background-color: none;
  margin: auto;
  height: 80%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  /*color: white;
  font-family: "Arial", Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;*/
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto
}

.myDiv1 {
  display: block;
}

.myDiv2 {
  display: none;
}

p {

}


.ul1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  height: 70px;
}
.li1 {
  float: right;
}
.li1 a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 25px    
}
.li1:first-child {
  margin-right: 100px;
}

/* Grow */
.hvr-grow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.hvr-grow:hover,
.hvr-grow:focus,
.hvr-grow:active {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.ul2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
}
.li2 {
  display: inline;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  width: 25%
}
.li2:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.li2 a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ul3 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.li3 {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

#myDiv1:checked ~ #myDiv .inner { margin-left:0; }
#myDiv2:checked ~ #myDiv .inner { margin-left:-100%; }
#myDiv3:checked ~ #myDiv .inner { margin-left:-200%; }
```

```html
<ul class="ul1">
  <li class="li1 hvr-grow"  ><a href="#sport" onclick="showDiv1()">SPORT</a>
  </li>
  <li class="li1 hvr-grow"><a href="#sportler" onclick="showDiv2()">SPORTLER</a>
  </li>
  <li class="lix">Meine Webseite</li>
</ul>


<div class="myDiv1" id="myDiv1">
  <ul class="ul3">
    <li class="li3"><a href="default.asp">Icon1</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="news.asp">Icon2</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="contact.asp">Icon3</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon4</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon5</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon6</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon7</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon8</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon9</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon10</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon11</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon12</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon13</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon14</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon15</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon16</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon17</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon18</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon19</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon20</a></li>
    <p  style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="myDiv2" id="myDiv2">my name</div>

<ul class="ul2">
  <li class="li2"><a href="#salman">Salman</a>
  </li>
  <li class="li2"><a href="#Patric">Patric</a>
  </li>
  <li class="li2"><a href="#IMIBE">IMIBE</a>
  </li>
  <li class="li2"><a href="#CUE">CUE</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: myDiv1 is undefined. it should be a string: `document.getElementById("myDiv1");`

Comment: changed it still doesnt work. but thanks!

Comment: store your js script into window.onload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double equal to sign '==' in the functions was the problem. It should just be a single '='. Now it works even without using any of the above suggestions. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
d1 = document.getElementById('myDiv1');
d2 = document.getElementById('myDiv2');

function showDiv1() {
 if (d1.className.indexOf('hide' > -1)) {
   d1.className.replace('hide', '');
            d1.className += ' show';
  }

 }

 function showDiv2() {
  if (d2.className.indexOf('hide' > -1)) {
    d2.className.replace('hide', '');
          d2.className += ' show';
   }
  }
```

```css
.ul2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
}
.li2 {
  display: inline;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  width: 25%
}
.li2:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.li2 a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.ul3 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.li3 {
  margin: 15px 0;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css">
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="ul1">
    <li class="li1 hvr-grow"><a href="#sport" onclick="showDiv1()">SPORT</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li1 hvr-grow"><a href="#sportler" onclick="showDiv2()">SPORTLER</a>
    </li>
    <li class="lix">Meine Webseite</li>
  </ul>


  <div class="myDiv1 hide" id="myDiv1">
    <ul class="ul3">
      <li class="li3"><a href="default.asp">Icon1</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="news.asp">Icon2</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="contact.asp">Icon3</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon4</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon5</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon6</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon7</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon8</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon9</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon10</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon11</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon12</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon13</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon14</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon15</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon16</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon17</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon18</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon19</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
      <li class="li3"><a href="about.asp">Icon20</a>
      </li>
      <p style="font-size: 0.85em;">This is the description of this sport</p>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv2 hide" id="myDiv2">my name</div>

  <ul class="ul2">
    <li class="li2"><a href="#salman">Salman</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="#Patric">Patric</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="#IMIBE">IMIBE</a>
    </li>
    <li class="li2"><a href="#CUE">CUE</a>
    </li>
  </ul>


</body>

</html>
```

```
 d1 = document.getElementById('myDiv1');
 d2 = document.getElementById('myDiv2');
```

`getElementById` takes in a string. You missed out the single quotes.

Also, there's no `pass` in Javascript. It should be a `return false`

Answer (score 0):

first change the getElementsById('whateverTheIdIs'):

```
d1 = document.getElementById('myDiv1');
d2 = document.getElementById('myDiv2');
```

second bind an onClick event to the corresponding element:

```
<li class="li1 hvr-grow"  ><a href="#sport" onclick="showDiv1()">SPORT</a>
</li>
<li class="li1 hvr-grow"><a href="#sportler" onclick="showDiv2()">SPORTLER</a>
</li>
```

third return false at the end of the showDiv1 and showDiv2 function to prevent the link from applying

Answer (score 0):

maybe the element doesn't exist when the your js code execute
to solve that
just store your js script inside onload event

```
window.onload = function() {

    d1 = document.getElementById('myDiv1');
    d2 = document.getElementById('myDiv2');
    function showDiv1() {
       if( d2.style.display == "block" )
       {
          d2.style.display = "none";
          d1.style.display = "block";
       }
       else
       {
          pass;
       }
    }

    function showDiv2() {
       if( d1.style.display == "block" )
       {
          d1.style.display = "none";
          d2.style.display = "block";
       }
       else
       {
          pass;
       }
    }
}
```